# how to enable quotas

Tags: configuration, quota

Can someone please explain the process of enabling quotas in developer edition. I have given all permissions like: Enable forecast, allow forecast, Show quotas. But when I enable user in forecast hierarchy, it is not getting enabled. And I am not finding the quota related lit under user detail page. I don't know where I have missed.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the API or dataloader to import quotas for Collaborative Forecasting. There is also an app in the app exchange providing a user interface: [Edit Quotas](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B41EqEAJ).

Answer (score -1):

Go to Set Up > Customize > Quotes | Check the **Enable Quotes** checkbox

[image]

Comment: Quotas, not quotes.